# DomDocument -> outputting changed html

Tags: javascript, php, html

below is my current code that pulls the html

BEFORE

```
<td class="winner betting-movement">
                11/8<img src="/images/site/blue-arrow-small.gif" width="6" height="11">6/4          </td>
```

Then replaces images with text

After

```
 <html><body><td class="winner betting-movement">$movement =  $article->childNodes->item(12)->ownerDocument->saveHTML($article->childNodes->item(12))."<br />";



                    <? php @$dom3->loadHTML($movement);
                     $xpath5 = new DOMXPath($dom3);
                    foreach($xpath5->query('//img[contains(@src, "blue")]') as $link) {
    $link->parentNode->replaceChild($dom3->createTextNode(" > "), $link);
}
                    foreach($xpath5->query('//img[contains(@src, "red")]') as $link) {
    $link->parentNode->replaceChild($dom3->createTextNode(" < "), $link);
}
                echo    $dom3->saveHTML();?>
```

works great but all i need to do now is output the new saved html as just the inner text e.g "11/8 > 6/4"

```
echo    $dom3->saveHTML()->textContent;
```

sadly the last line doesn't work and im reaching out to see if anyone could point me in a quick fix for this?

Comment: Formatting your code to make it easy for others to read would make this question a lot more attractive to potential answerers...

Answer (score 0):

Can you do `echo htmlentities($dom3->saveHTML());` - this would encode the HTML to be viewable to the user. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: that gives me the whole html - i just need 11/8 &gt; 6/4

Comment: @JarrattPerkins, then change the question to represent that you need only specific text out of the generated html with more details.